# php set user agent while trying to get last redirect

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers, user-agent

hello I have the following code :

```
 function get_redirect_url($url){
        $redirect_url = null; 

        $url_parts = @parse_url($url);
        if (!$url_parts) return false;
        if (!isset($url_parts['host'])) return false; //can't process relative URLs
        if (!isset($url_parts['path'])) $url_parts['path'] = '/';

        $sock = fsockopen($url_parts['host'], (isset($url_parts['port']) ? (int)$url_parts['port'] : 80), $errno, $errstr, 30);
        if (!$sock) return false;

        $request = "HEAD " . $url_parts['path'] . (isset($url_parts['query']) ? '?'.$url_parts['query'] : '') . " HTTP/1.1\r\n"; 
        $request .= 'Host: ' . $url_parts['host'] . "\r\n"; 
        $request .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n"; 
        fwrite($sock, $request);
        $response = '';
        while(!feof($sock)) $response .= fread($sock, 8192);
        fclose($sock);

        if (preg_match('/^Location: (.+?)$/m', $response, $matches)){
            if ( substr($matches[1], 0, 1) == "/" )
                return $url_parts['scheme'] . "://" . $url_parts['host'] . trim($matches[1]);
            else
                return trim($matches[1]);

        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

second function:

```
function get_all_redirects($url){
        $redirects = array();
        while ($newurl = get_redirect_url($url)){
            if (in_array($newurl, $redirects)){
                break;
            }
            $redirects[] = $newurl;
            $url = $newurl;
        }
        return $redirects;
    }
```

third function:

```
 function get_final_url($url){
        $redirects = get_all_redirects($url);
        if (count($redirects)>0){
            return array_pop($redirects);
        } else {
            return $url;
        }
    }
```

when I try to use the code below:

```
echo get_final_url("https://www.facebook.com/9gag");
```

this is what I get :

```
https://www.facebook.com/unsupportedbrowser
```

I think it's because I should add an user agent for my function . 
any help is appreciated.

Comment: You could be right. Add an user agent string. Something like this `$request .= "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0\r\n";`

Comment: Well, have you tried adding a UA header to your request?